# Atlassian API throws error for attaching file in API

Tags: python, jira

```
def attach_file_using_path(issue, path):
    jira.add_attachment(issue=issue, attachment=path)

File "C:\Users\NK077651\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\jira\utils\__init__.py", line 41, in __init__
for key, value in super(CaseInsensitiveDict, self).items():

RuntimeError: dictionary keys changed during iteration
```

Comment: Github issue on Jira's repo: https://github.com/pycontribs/jira/issues/890 (found by googling "jira dictionary keys changed during iteration") Apparently this is due to a change in Python 3.8. You need to manually install version 3 (which for some reason is not on pypi yet)

Comment: yea I read that too installing 3.7 interpreter would solve I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change python interpreter to 3.7